# Calculating upper and lower bound

Tags: functions, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose there is a function
$\ f(x)= 19n^2/5n +1-n $
I want to calculate upper and lower bound. But I had this confusion that whether I have to calculate in terms of n^2? Because dominating term is n^2

or If I solve the above equation as $\ f(x)= 19n/5 +1-n  $ (canceling n in 1st term) then what? Then I have to calculate c1 and c2 in terms of n? because that will be the dominating term.

So, Kindly tell me that in which term do I have to calculate c1 and c2 i.e n or n^2?? Can I cancel n in $\ 19n^2/5n $ or not? What will be its asymptotic form? $\ f(n)∈Θ(n^2) $ or $\ f(n)∈Θ(n) $ ?

Comment: $\dfrac{19n^2}{5n}=\dfrac{19n}{5}$, you can use either assuming your function is $f(n)=\dfrac{19n^2}{5n}+1-n$.

Comment: i can also assume $\  f(n)=19n/5+1−n $ ??

Comment: @YadatiKiran What will be its asymptotic form?  f(n)∈Θ(n2) or  f(n)∈Θ(n) ?

Comment: Yes. Its asymptotic form will be a function of $n$ in its least possible exponent.